# Java run a program silently using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, process

I want to run an executable file that generates a window with `Next` buttons. I want to suppress that window and somehow "press" the `Next` buttons without the knowledge of the user.
So far, I've only managed to run the executable, and I understood that I can use specific parameters to run it silently, but I do not have information about those parameters.

```
public class Process extends Thread {

public void run(){
        try{

            System.out.println("Start");

            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("path to executable");
            java.lang.Process process = processBuilder.start();

            System.out.println("End");
        }catch(IOException exception){
            System.out.println(exception);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're going about this the wrong way. You want multiple programs to communicate, is that it?

Comment: No, I am assigned to build a program that runs some executable files. These file generate some windows with `Next` buttons. What I want is to suppress these windows and press those buttons. I do not want my user to know I have opened those programs.

Comment: Are these programs just random ones ? Have you checked if they haven't implemented their own silent mode ? If so, you could just run this programs by giving the good parameters with your `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: They are not random, and they do not have silent mode. You know what the parameter for silent execution is?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to cause confusion, maybe even access data without their knowledge, and I'm not an advocater of that. That's not what Java's for. Find another method.

Comment: There isn't just a 'global' silent mode parameter. They are implemented by the editor's software and if they didn't do it, you just can't bypass the windows.

Comment: I'm just trying to group some executables under one program, but they have to install automatically, without user interaction. The user knows that the programs will be installed, but he doesn't have to press the `Next` buttons. Furthermore, I'll try to suppress the windows, but make a `javafx` window that will display the progress

Comment: I understand and it's not possible. You can't change the behavior of a program if it wasn't designed to.
As an example [msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Silent-or-Unattended-Installation) implementation of Git provide some silent mode installation so here you could use it.
Otherwise there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `doClick()` method.

[doClick() method doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29)

Also, in addition you might take a look at JNI or JNA tool which serves as wrappers.

Comment: Is there a way to find the `Next` button of the external program?

Comment: You can't get a reference to the button of an external application (easily). So I don't think this is helpful here.

Comment: You can try using JNI or JNA tool which serves as a wrapper.

Comment: @Techidiot I have found this and it might work with what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to install some .exe silently you can use Msiexec with parameters and you can call it with ProcessBuilder. You can find more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee251019(v=bts.10).aspx).

Comment: `ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("Msiexec.exe", "path to executable", "/quiet");` I have done this, but it opens up a window that specifies some details about `Msiexec.exe`